# Inverse of $\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, inverse, approximation

I am trying to invert (or to estimate the inverse of) 
$$y=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$$
for $y\in(0,1)$. The function 'looks' monotonically decreasing between $x=0$ and $x=\infty$, but I have not been able to show this.

[image: Plot of y=(1-Exp[-x])/x against x]

I have been able to compute the inverse function numerically, but I am wondering if there is an analytical solution or approximation that would help speed things up.

Mathematica tells me that the inverse is 
$$x=\frac{1+y\cdot\text{ProductLog}[-e^{-1/y}/y]}{y}$$
where $\text{ProductLog}[z]$ is the solution to $z=we^w$. I have tried re-arranging the latter expression but I cannot arrive at the original function. Plotting the latter function on $y\in(0,1)$, it looks plausible, but I don't want to use this formula without understanding where it comes from.

[image: Plot of x against y]

Can anyone show me how to invert the original function or help me estimate the inverse to some degree of precision?

Comment: I don't get. You already know the inverse function depends on the Lambert function, so you just have to check Lambert function asymptotics on the related Wikipedia page. Or you may solve $y=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ through Newton's method with starting point $x_0=-2\log(y)$.

Comment: Thanks, I did know know about the Lambert function. I will investigate it.

Comment: OK using the asymptotics of the Lambert function I think I can approximate Mathematica's formula for the inverse. However, I would still like to know how to arrive at Mathematica's answer for the inverse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derivation to obtain the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) :
\begin{align}
y&=\frac{1-e^{-x}}x\\
x&=\frac{1-e^{-x}}y\\
x\,e^x&=\frac{e^{x}-1}y\\
\left(x-\frac 1y\right)\,e^x&=-\frac 1y\\
\left(x-\frac 1y\right)\,e^{\large{x-\frac 1y}}&=-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\\
x-\frac 1y&=W\left(-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\right)\\
\end{align}
and the wished formula : $\quad\boxed{\displaystyle x=\frac 1y+W\left(-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\right)}$

At this point (as indicated by robjohn) we may use the fact that $\;y\in(0,1)\;$ and observe that the parameter of the Lambert-$W$ function $\,-\dfrac 1y\;e^{-\large{\frac 1y}}\;$ will belong to $\;\left(-\dfrac 1e,\;0\right)$.

The implications are :

- for any $\,y\in(0,1)\;$ we have two real solutions from the two branches of the Lambert-$W$ function (see the picture in the Wikipedia link and the discussion about the image of $W$ under or above $-1$ corresponding to the parameter $-\dfrac 1e$) :$$x_1=\frac 1y+W\left(-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\right),\;x_2=\frac 1y+W_{-1}\left(-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\right)$$
- the parameter of $W$ may be written as $\;u\,e^u\,$ for $u=-\dfrac 1y\;$ but $\;W_{-1}(u\,e^u)=u\;$ in the second case so that $\;x_2=\dfrac 1y-\dfrac 1y\;$ with the solutions becoming simply :
  $$x_1=\frac 1y+W\left(-\frac {\large{e^{-\frac 1y}}}y\right),\ x_2=0$$
  ($x_2=0$ is rather a solution of $\:x\;y=1-e^{-x}\;$ than of the initial equation)

Comment: Since the argument is negative, it should be noted that there are two branches of $\mathrm{W}$. This is important since one value of $\mathrm{W}\left(-\frac1ye^{-\frac1y}\right)$ is $-\frac1y$ which gives $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks @robjohn: (I didn't notice the bounds on $y$) I'll edit this again. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! How do you get from the 4th line to the 5th line in your derivation?

Comment: @js86: It is a multiplication by $e^{-1/y}$ and the previous line is a subtraction of $e^x/y$.

Comment: of course, thanks!

Comment: I can get $y\to1^-$ as $x\to0^+$ using l'Hopital's rule, too. How do you get the line $\frac{-1}{y}e^{-1/y}=-1/e$?

Comment: @js86: the argument of $W$ must be $\ge -1/e$ (see the link) I suppose it equal to be able to use the $W$ function.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: since the argument is $-\frac1ye^{-\frac1y}$, it will always be $\ge-\frac1e$.

Comment: You are right @robjohn but I obtained the constraint on $y$ in the reverse order first (I mean that for $y>1$ $W$ would not return real values)... But you are right I should start with the constraints from the question..

Comment: Thanks @RaymondManzoni, this is exactly the kind of explanation I was hoping for.

Comment: Glad it clarified things @js86! Fine continuation,