# graph of $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, functions

i am trying to draw the graph of $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

its domain is $\mathbb{R}$-$0$ but its limit is $1$ in the neighbourhood of zero.

Also $$lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$$ so negative X axis is asymptote.

also $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{(x-1)e^x+1}{x^2}$$

so $f(x)$ is increasing in $(0 \: \infty)$ and decreasing in $(-\infty \:0)$

now the ambiguity is $f(-\infty) \to 0$ and $f(0^-) \to 1$ but $f(x)$ is decreasing in negative interval.

Comment: The derivative is positive for $x<0\lor x>0$ so $f$ is increasing in both intervals

Comment: Concerning the graph of $f(−x)$ (the horizontal 'mirror' of your function) as well as of its inverse (the 'bisector mirror') see this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425588/inverse-of-frac1-e-xx-on-0-1).

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity. The mistake is when you claim that $f$ is decreasing in$(-\infty,0)$ since for $x<0$ you still have
$f'(x)=\frac{(x-1)e^x+1}{x^2}>0$.

This is because of the well-known $e^x \ge x+1$ for all $x$, in particular 
$1-x \le e^{-x}$ i.e. $(1-x)e^x \le 1$ and hence $(x-1)e^x+1 \ge 0$.

So $f$ is increasing everywhere which goes along with $f(-\infty)<f(0)$

See also here for the graph: [www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e^x-1%29%2Fx](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Fx)